# I need 50 reputation to post a comment, how can I gain reputation without commenting?

Tags: discussion, comments, reputation

Honestly I think the title says it all, but I'm happy to elaborate where needed.

Comment: For reference, [the Help Center page for the "comment everywhere" privilege](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment) links to [this Help Center page about what reputation is and how to earn it](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation).

Comment: I'm not in a position to search now, but hard to believe this is not a duplicate of some other question.

Comment: @Kirt There are duplicates on meta.se, but I can’t find one here.

Answer (score 15):

Post interesting questions and useful answers to questions. Upvotes on those will give you reputation. Being able to comment is among the first perks gained by gaining reputation.

As a closely related side note, you do not receive reputation for comments. (With thanks to ntsua60 and V2Blast).

Comment: Worth noting that no amounting of commenting ever gains one rep?

Comment: Yep, that was the other thing I forgot to point out in my comment above.

Comment: A possible point of confusion is that answers are not comments.  This is a comment, responding to an answer.